# Ruby on Rails: Elastic Search Showing All the Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, rubygems

I have added the elastic search gem and added a search button on the navbar however, when i want the user to search for posts it asks me to login or sign up. I want the user to be able to view the index page of the post and i added a before_filter in the posts_controller file but i don't know why it keeps asking me to sign up or log in. Here's my code:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user! , except: [:index,:show]
  before_filter :check_user, only: [:edit,:update,:destroy]



  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json

  def search
    if params[:search].present?
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
    else
    @posts = Post.all
    end
  end

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @posts = Post.all
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @reviews = Review.where(post_id: @post.id)
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end


  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description,:image,:all_tags)
    end

    def check_user
      if  current_user.id != @post.user_id
      redirect_to root_path , alert: "Sorry this Post belongs to someone else"
    end
    end

end
```

Comment: Are you possibly calling  `authenticate_user!` inside of application_controller? Also, you should stick to restful routes and have search inside of the index action.  Have you tried using `binding.pry` to see where it's getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user! , :only => [:index,:show]
```

in your controller for skipping the before_filter for those actions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by adding the search method to the before_action post authentication. Here's the code:

```
  before_action :authenticate_user! , except: [:index,:show,:search]
```